# Alternative definition for carmichael function

Tags: number-theory, carmichael-function

As my textbook describes it, the Carmichael function is the minimum integer *m* such that, for all *a* coprime with *n*, $$a^m \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$$

So, as far as I understand it, *m* is the minimum number that:

1. divides $\phi(n)$ (because it is the order of a subgroup and for Lagrange theorem divides the order of the group).
2. is divided by the order of every subgroup generated by any *a* s.t. $(a,n) = 1$

So my question is: wouldn't this make *m* the *least common multiple* of the order of every subgroup generated by any *a* with $(a,n) = 1$?

Comment: Yes, it would. ${}$

Comment: Thank you. Does this have something to do with the factorization of the group of integers mod n? I've noticed a property of Carmichael function is l(mn) = lcm(l(n), l(m)) which kind of reminds me of group factorization.